# First Asynctask works however, Second doesn't when button pressed

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have seen all the answers to the previous questions however, can't understand the code to my needs and a bit confused.

I am trying to run two `AsyncTasks` simultaneously which are place in two different classes when pressed button in my third class. I understand I need to used `executeOnExecutor` but what I can't understand where and what should be the contents to my needs of it. Do I use in both the classes when I'm implementing individually or in the third class where I'm executing when button is pressed.

Code of third class where I'm executing AsyncTask:

```
     new NewAppliance().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
     new NewChecksAndOperations().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

In both class where these are implemented, I'm targeting `HONEYCOMB` too as:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11) 
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

Comment: This all looks fine at first glance... Why are you turning off `StrictMode` though?

Comment: Where ? I don't think I am :/

Comment: `new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll()`...  Why do this?

Comment: To be honest, I'm unaware of the concept of strict mode. What do you think I should do.

Comment: I think if you don't have a specific reason to put it there you should remove it.  Regarding launching the threads: are they actually launching?  If they are, then I think your calling code looks fine.

Comment: I have removed it however still only the first one is working

Comment: Please define "working" versus "not working."  Edit your question.

Comment: The `NewAppliances AsyncTask` is working however `NewChecksAndOpertions AsyncTask` isn't working

Comment: Check your logcat for exceptions and try debugging.

Comment: i did, its not even calling the second one

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you are already doing it right.

[executeOnExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...))() works on a specific AsyncTask instance, hence has to be called for each 
and every AsyncTask instance for which you want it to take effect.

That is, you can either call:

```
new MyAsyncTask(..).execute();  // <----  standard
```

For standard execution, or:

```
new MyAsyncTask(..).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

For parallel execution.

As I'm sure you already know, default execute() behavior for Android >= 3.0 is sequential processing.
Remeber to both instantiate and execute() (or executeOnExecutor()) your AsyncTasks from the UI thread,

Finally, and I understand this is not the subject of your questions, please make a habit of wrapping all
of your StrictMode processing within a DEBUG test:

```
boolean isDebuggable = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));

if (isDebuggable ) {
       set StrictMode here..
}
```

br>
You do not want StrictMode tests running at your users...

**EDIT**

To test a fixed pool executor (instead of an AsyncTask) do as follows:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     pool.execute(new Runnable() {
           public void run() { 
               // do something with no UI access!
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: I'm sure I'm not because only the first `AsyncTask` is being call not the second one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion though. But can you please point out what I'm doing wrong please as I have removed `StrictMode` as suggested by @thirtythree. Still no luck

Comment: frankly i am surprised. on a 'reasonably' modern android THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR is configured to handle 5 and more parallel threads where needed, which should result in 'parallel' activation of your asyncTasks. You are saying it does not happen and I believe you. Can you, just for test sake, replace AsyncTasks with STANDARD EXECUTORS (see my EDIT in orig post) at tell me what happens

Comment: I know.. I have tried the standard approach already too `new NewChecksAndOperations().execute();` its still not executing. I have just tried to execute only one asynctask `NewChecksAndOperations()` on its own and this still doesn't get executed.

Comment: Do I do that when I press the button ?

Comment: I have tried the `ExecutorService` in the button code and execute `AsyncTasks` in it but still doesn't work